# Elasticsearch HTTP 500 Error {"message":null}

Tags: elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am encountering error from _bulk endpoint but I can't solve since the error message sent by ES is null. I am calling the _bulk endpoint via ES REST API. This only happens intermittently.

I already tried replicating it via load testing but I still am not able to do so.

Here is a snippet of the stacktrace I am getting:

`HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error{"message":null}    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:354) at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:343) at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436) at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`